# How to create color variables with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am not sure if this is possible. But the concept is similar to SASS variables but using jQuery instead. So lets say I wanted to have reusable CSS attributes for jQuery. For example...

**I want to make a variable that I can reuse for the color black**

```
var black = .css('color','#000');
var white = .css('color','#FFF');
```

This obviously doesn't work because the syntax is wrong... but you get the picture I hope.. So then later I  could do this...

```
$('#myelement').css(black);
```

Is it possible to do something like this?

Comment: Pass an object. var white = {color: "#000"}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2) can take a map of key-value pairs that represent the CSS attributes. Therefore, you could store and use key-value pairs with the desired CSS attributes.

```
var black = {'color': '#000'};
var white = {'color': '#FFF'};

$('#myelement').css(black);
```

These can contain any number of attributes. For example:

```
var headingStyle = {'background-color': '#C00', 'color': '#FFF'};
$('h1#heading').css(headingStyle);
```

You could even create new styles based on a certain style and add attributes to them:

```
var mainHeadingStyle = $.extend({'font-size': '50px'}, headingStyle);
$('h1#main').css(mainHeadingStyle);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an object to you css() call.
Do this:

```
var white = {'color' : '#fff'};
var black = {'color' : '#000'};
$('#myElement').css(white); 
$('#otherElement').css(black);
```